# What is the lifetime of a C++ method pointer expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I have a generic function that invokes a callable it's handed; the moral equivalent of a call to `std::invoke`, except it's part of a coroutine:

```cpp
// Wait for some condition to be true, then invoke f with the supplied
// arguments. The caller must ensure that all references remain valid
// until the returned task is done.
template <typename F, typename Args...>
Task<void> WaitForConditionAndInvoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  co_await SomeCondition();
  std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Because of the requirement that the input arguments remain valid, it's not always legal to pass `WaitForConditionAndInvoke` a temporary like a lambda (unless e.g. the returned task is directly `co_await`ed as part of a single expression). This is true even if using unary `+` to convert a lambda with no bound state to a function pointer: the function pointer is itself a temporary, and asan seems to correctly complain about using it after it's destroyed.

My question is whether using a member function pointer is legal:

```
struct Object {
  void SomeMethod();
};

// Some global object; we're not worried about the object's lifetime.
Object object;

Task<void> WaitForConditionAndInvokeOnGlobalObject() {
  return WaitForConditionAndInvoke(&Object::SomeMethod, &object);
}
```

This seems to work fine, but it's unclear to me what the lifetime of the pointer that `&Object::SomeMethod` evaluates to is. Is this guaranteed to be a constant expression, i.e. not a temporary? What part of the standard covers this?

Comment: `&Object::SomeMethod` is a constant expression https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#11

Comment: There's nothing special about member function pointers. The lifetime issue is identical to passing `42` as a parameter. See also https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#note-3

Comment: Yep you're right, a literal `42` is the same issue, but only if you know the answer to the question, i.e. that `&Object::SomeMethod` is a constant expression. :-) Thanks for the citation, @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.

Comment: _it's unclear to me what the lifetime of the pointer that `&Object::SomeMethod` evaluates to is_ There is no lifetime since there is no object involved. _Is this guaranteed to be a constant expression, i.e. not a temporary?_ Why constant expressions are relevant here and how they exclude temporary objects?

Answer (score 3):

That `WaitForConditionAndInvoke` coroutine will be dangerous unless every argument including the functor `f` refers to an object with lifetime long enough. For example, `WaitForConditionAndInvoke(std::abs, 1)` has undefined behavior because of the object materialized to initialize a reference with the `int` prvalue expression `1`. There is no difference per the Standard for constant expression arguments here, although a constant expression value could help compilers implement it in a way which "works" using a dead object's known value.

To fix this, you could have your function move every rvalue argument into a local object:

```
// All rvalue arguments are moved from.
// The caller must make sure all lvalue arguments remain valid until
// the returned task is done.
template <typename F, typename Args...>
Task<void> WaitForConditionAndInvoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  // local_f could be declared an lvalue reference or object,
  // but not an rvalue reference:
  F local_f(std::forward<F>(f));
  // Similarly, the template arguments to tuple are lvalue references
  // or object types.
  std::tuple<Args...> local_args(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  co_await SomeCondition();
  std::apply(std::forward<F>(local_f), std::move(local_args));
}
```

Or to be even safer, do as `std::bind` does, and move/copy everything. The calling code can specify that the functor or functor argument(s) should be treated as a reference with no move or copy using `std::ref` or `std::cref`. In fact, that implementation is just:

```
// All arguments are moved or copied from.
// A std::reference_wrapper can be used to skip the move/copy of
// the referenced object.
template <typename F, typename Args...>
Task<void> WaitForConditionAndInvoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  auto bound_f = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  co_await SomeCondition();
  bound_f();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand that I can copy/move a `std::decay_t<F>` and so on, and in real code that would likely be the right thing to do, but this is a contrived case and that's not really what I'm asking about. Your line about prvalues is more what I'm looking for. Do you have standard citations you can give?

Comment: I'll try to update the answer at some point. But the main points are [class.temporary]/(6.9) "A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call" and [intro.execution]/11 "For each function invocation or evaluation of an await-expression _F_, ...; if _F_ invokes or resumes a coroutine ([expr.await]), only evaluations subsequent to the previous suspension (if any) and prior to the next suspension (if any) are considered to occur within _F_." (for purposes of happens-before ordering)

Comment: Thanks, and this seems like a dumb question, but what about the fact that `1` and `&Object::SomeMethod` cause temporaries to be created? That's the citation I'm really looking for.

Comment: [\[dcl.init.ref\]/(5.3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.ref#5.3) says that when a reference is initialized and the initializer after any needed user-defined conversion is a prvalue, the temporary materialization conversion ([\[conv.rval\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/conv.rval)) is applied.

Answer (score -1):

As the commenters say, there's no lifetime issue here. `&Object::SomeMethod` is a constant expression, just like `42` or `&WaitForConditionAndInvokeOnGlobalObject`.

You might have confused yourself by naming your type `struct Object`, so the expression `&Object::SomeMethod` kind of *looks* like it involves an object... but it doesn't; `Object` is the name of a *type*. There is no object involved in that expression; it's a simple compile-time constant, just like `offsetof(Object, SomeDataMember)` or `sizeof(Object)` would be.

No object involved = no lifetime issues involved.

EDIT (thus completely changing my answer): Ah, aschepler is right, you're concerned with the lifetime of the thing-referred-to-by-`F&& f` in

```
template <typename F, typename Args...>
Task<void> WaitForConditionAndInvoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  co_await SomeCondition();
  std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

which is the temporary object with value `&Object::SomeMethod`, which of course dies at the end of its full-expression, i.e., at the semicolon at the end of `return WaitForConditionAndInvoke(&Object::SomeMethod, &object);`. As soon as you hit that semicolon, all of the temporaries go out of scope and any references to them (like, that `f` captured in the coroutine frame) are definitely dangling.

Comment: The object of concern is the one created by the temporary materialization associated with binding rvalue reference `f` to the expression `&Object::SomeMethod`. A reference always refers to some actual object (or function).